# ¿como puedo definir el tipo de una variable en el main si quiero que sea de una clase?

Tags: c++, clase, class

he creado una clase para usar fracciones y a la hora de trabajar en el main defino la variable como Fraccion v;, siendo Fraccion el nombre de mi clase y de da error.
La clase trabaja con la fracción separando el numerador y el denominador.

> error: no matching function for call to 'Fraccion::Fraccion()')

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Fraccion
{
    private:
        int num,den;
    public:
        Fraccion(Fraccion &obj)
        {
            num=obj.num;
            den=obj.den;
        }
    ~Fraccion()=default;

    int mcm(Fraccion v , Fraccion u)
    {
        int mcd=0;
        int a = max(v.den, u.den);
        int b = min(v.den, u.den);
        do
        {
            mcd = b;
            b= a%b;
            a=mcd;
        } while (b!=0);
        return mcd;
    }

    Fraccion& suma(Fraccion v, Fraccion u,Fraccion r)
    {
        r.den= mcm(u,v);
        r.num=(v.num * u.den) + (v.den * u.num);
        return r;
    }
 friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &out, const Fraccion & c)
{
    out << '(' << c.num << '/' << c.den << ')' ;
    return out;
}
};
int main()
{
    Fraccion v;
    int opcion;
    cout << "dame una fraccion" << endl;
    cin >> v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El compilador te está indicando que la clase `Fraccion` no tiene constructor por defecto. El constructor por defecto es aquel que no recibe parámetros, por eso se muestra con el paréntesis vacío en el error:

> ```
> no matching function for call to Fraccion::Fraccion()
> //                          No hay parámetros ----> ^
> ```

Y esto es así, porque cuando has creado una instancia de `Fracción`, no has pasado ningún parámetro a la instancia:

```
Fraccion v;
//       ^ <---- No se le pasan parámetros para construir.
```

Puedes solucionarlo diciendo al compilador que cree el constructor por defecto (como has hecho con el destructor, aunque no fuese necesario en este caso):

```
public:
    Fraccion(Fraccion &obj)
    {
        num=obj.num;
        den=obj.den;
    }
~Fraccion()=default;
Fraccion()=default; // Constructor por defecto.
```